# Could some one help me about this proof? it is about closure.

Tags: proof-verification

Let E ⊆ R be nonempty and bounded above, and define s = sup(E). Show that s ∈the  closure of E.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Use the fact that $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an uperbound for $E$.